# How to import Product API on ebaysdk?

Tags: python, ebay-api

I am trying to find information (description, title, images, aspects, and basically everything) on a product by using a UPC. I managed to do so by using eBay's trading API (GetItem) and productID. However, when I am trying to do it with a UPC I encounter problems. There is not much instructions on the web. I found the function [`getProductDetails`](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/product/CallRef/getProductDetails.html), which is supposed to answer my question:

This is my code:

```
from ebaysdk.trading import Connection
api = Connection(devid=dev_id, certid=cert_id, appid=app_id, token=token_id, globalId="EBAY-US", config_file=None) 
response = api.execute('getProductDetails', {"productDetailsRequest": {"dataset": {"UPC": "#UPCNUMBER"}}})
r = response.dict()
print(r)
```

However, when I tried to use the same API (trading) I got this error:

```
ConnectionError: 'getProductDetails: Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 2, Unsupported API call. The API call "getProductDetails" is invalid or not supported in this release.'
```

I tried to understand what API exactly I should use, but there is no information on the internet. From the documentation, I can understand that that is a Product API. However, when looking at the different `ebaysdk.xxx` sub-modules, I don't see any sub-module which fits.

Does somebody know anything about this?